# Image doesn't print when event is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want draw a image when I mousedown is fired, but I can't.

What should I fix?

```js
var brush = new Image();
brush.src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designcontest/vintage/256/Brush-icon.png"

brush.onload = function(){
    $("<canvas></canvas>").appendTo("body");
 var canvas = $('canvas');
 var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
 canvas.width(500).height(300); 
  
 $('canvas').mousedown(function(event){
        alert('canvas clicked on coordinates ('+event.pageX+','+event.pageY+')'); 
     contex.drawImage(brush, event.pageX, event.pageY);  
 })  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistyped the word "context":

```
contex.drawImage(brush, event.pageX, event.pageY);
```

should be

```
context.drawImage(brush, event.pageX, event.pageY);
```